# Can't add an extension to a quarkus project

Tags: java, gradle, quarkus

I tried to add an extension with command  `.\gradlew addExtension --extensions=io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-mutiny --stacktrace`. I got the following error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: No platforms detected in the project
        at io.quarkus.gradle.tasks.QuarkusPlatformTask.platformDescriptor(QuarkusPlatformTask.java:45)
        at io.quarkus.gradle.tasks.QuarkusPlatformTask.getQuarkusProject(QuarkusPlatformTask.java:188)
        at io.quarkus.gradle.tasks.QuarkusAddExtension_Decorated.getQuarkusProject(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.gradle.tasks.QuarkusAddExtension.addExtension(QuarkusAddExtension.java:59)
```

I figured something is lacking in the configuration, but I can't find what.

My `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
    id 'io.quarkus'
}

repositories {
    // Use JCenter for resolving dependencies.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation group: 'io.quarkus', name: 'quarkus-resteasy', version: '1.12.2.Final'
    implementation group: 'io.quarkus', name: 'quarkus-resteasy-mutiny', version: '1.12.2.Final'


}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'wells.App'
}
```

Comment: Looks like the `build.gradle` is not properly set up. Can you share the `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Turing85 added

Comment: Ii am not an expert on gradle but looking at [this github project](https://github.com/JosemyDuarte/quarkus-terraform-lambda-demo), I would say you are missing a `implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")`. Also, please take a look at the `gradle.properties` and `settings.gradle`.

Comment: @Turing85 I added it right before your comment :) Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: @Turing85 mind adding that as answer so people can easily find the future without having to read the comments?

Comment: Not necessary. A - in my opinion - [satisfactory answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66691962/4216641) already exists. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `--extensions` parameter of the `addExtension` task does not take Maven coordinates but extension names without the `quarkus-` prefix, like so:

```sh
% ./gradlew addExtension --extensions="hibernate-validator"

> Task :addExtension
? Extension io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-validator has been installed
```

Additionally, I strongly recommend to let Quarkus manage the dependency versions for you. Quarkus is an opinionated framework and puts a lot of effort into managing dependencies for us. To take advantage of that, add an `enforcedPlatform` clause to your `build.gradle` script. Example:

```
dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:1.12.2.Final")
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation group: 'io.quarkus', name: 'quarkus-resteasy'
    implementation group: 'io.quarkus', name: 'quarkus-resteasy-mutiny'
    // Unit and integration tests
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
}
```